# Semantic UI transition doesn't work on jQuery array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have an array of jQuery objects that I'd like for one of which to transition based on its index.

This code works:

```
$('.page').transition()
```

So does this:

```
$('$page').transition()
```

However, the first one transitions all objects with the page class and that's not the desired result. The second one doesn't transition based on index, which is also not the desired result.

This is what I'd like to work:

```
$('page')[0].transition()
```

It, however, doesn't work and gives this error:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].transition is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jquery filter selectors. For this context, you can use `:eq(index)` on your selector. Your code is going to be like this:

`$('.page:eq(0)').transition();`